# Linear elliptic equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables, harmonic-analysis, differential-operators, harmonic-functions

Let $\Delta:=\partial_z\,\partial_{\overline {z}} $ be the Laplacian operator. I look for a particular non-trivial solution $u$ of $$\Delta u=\frac{a}{1-|z|^2}u$$ where $u\in C^2(\mathbb{D})$ and $a\in\mathbb{C} $.

Comment: Letting $u=f(r)$ be radial, your PDE becomes the ODE $f''+\frac{1}{r}f'-\frac{a}{1-r^2}f=0$.

Comment: [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=f%27%27%5C%2840%29r%5C%2841%29%2B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2Cr%5D%5C%2841%29f%27%5C%2840%29r%5C%2841%29-Divide%5Ba%2C1-Power%5Br%2C2%5D%5Df%5C%2840%29r%5C%2841%29%3D0) gives the solution as a linear combination of the Meijer G-function $G^{2,0}_{2,2}$ and the hypergeometric function $_{2}F_1$ in the radial case.

Comment: Thank you Zachary for your answer, but I want to know, what about the tangential derivative $\partial_\theta u(re^{i\theta})$? Because the function $u$ depends on the variables $z$ and $\overline{z}$.
knowing that:
$$\partial_z=\frac{1}{2}e^{-i\theta}\bigg(\partial_r-\frac{i}{r}\partial_\theta\bigg)$$
and $$\partial_{\overline{z}}=\frac{1}{2}e^{i\theta}\bigg(\partial_r+\frac{i}{r}\partial_\theta\bigg).$$
So the Laplacian operator can be $$\Delta=\frac{\partial^2_r}{\partial r^2}+\frac{\partial_r}{r\partial r}+\frac{\partial^2_\theta}{\partial\theta^2}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is happily linear, so depending on the domain you may find separable analytical solutions to the Dirichlet problem thanks to Sturm–Liouville.

For instance, let's take the domain to be a unit circle and set $u(r=1,\theta)=f(\theta)$ as boundary value. Construct the solution as

\begin{align}
u(r,\theta)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[A_n\cos n\theta+B_n\sin n\theta\right]\frac{R^{(a)}_n(r)}{R^{(a)}_n(1)},
\end{align}

where

\begin{align}
A_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\: f(\theta)\cos n\theta\:,\:\:\:B_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\: f(\theta)\sin n\theta,
\end{align}

and $R^{(a)}_n(r)$ satisfies

\begin{align}
\frac{d^2R^{(a)}_n}{dr^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{dR^{(a)}_n}{dr}-\left[\frac{a}{1-r^2}+n^2\right]R^{(a)}_n=0.
\end{align}

This last equation has in general two linearly independent solutions, but only one of them is well behaved as $r\rightarrow 0 $.

For $n=0$ (which is the full solution if $f(\theta)$ is constant) one has, as rightly mentioned by [Zachary](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438288/linear-elliptic-equation#comment1130075_438288), one solution that can be written in terms of Meijer G-functions, but has no $r\rightarrow 0 $ limit so we exclude it. The other one is

\begin{align}
R^{(a)}_0=\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{i \sqrt{a}}{2},\frac{i \sqrt{a}}{2};1;r^2\right).
\end{align}